# Structure in structure, initialization

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

How to initialize an inner structure inside the outer structure?

```
struct TOuter
{
   struct TInner
   {
       bool b1, b2;
       TInner () : b1 (false), b2(false) {}
   };

   bool b3;

   TOuter (): TOuter::TInner(), b3(true) {} // Error
};
```

Comment: Retagged C++, hoping it really *is* c++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you have no object of the `TInner` struct, so there's no need to initialize anything.

Other than that, it's just the same as with any other class/struct type:

```
struct TOuter
{
   struct TInner
   {
       bool b1, b2;
       TInner () : b1 (false), b2(false) {}
   };

   bool b3;

   TInner foo;

   TOuter (): foo(), b3(true) { // member variable
     TInner x; // local variable
   }
};

TOuter::TInner out; // need qualified name, bc. TInner is not in scope
...
bar(TOuter::TInner()); // temporary
```

Comment: Removed the unnecessary passage from this answer (as it's already present in the question).

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of TInner inside TOuter.

```
struct TOuter
{
   struct TInner
   {
       bool b1, b2;
       TInner () : b1 (false), b2(false) {}
   };

   TInner inner;
   bool b3;

   TOuter (): inner(), b3(true) {}
};
```

You can also do it by writing the variable name right after the struct like this:

```
    struct TInner
    {
        bool b1, b2;
        TInner () : b1 (false), b2(false) {}
    } inner;
```